# Will frequent update to redux store damage app performance

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have react native app that use redux.
I have a lot reducers so in redux store I keep data like: user, auth, orders, items, feeds etc.
So all app data are in there.
I have one reducer that I update a lot.
In it I just keep one value and that is current coordinate I track user movement and I like to keep that value in there.
My question is if I constantly update that one value does redux update whole app again causing render everywhere or it just update that one value and update just views that render this property?

Comment: I am not completely sure, but I think that all your mounted views accessing this property will update. A way to filter which view you want to update would be to filter if your component needs to refresh in `shouldComponentUpdate()`. Take a look at this [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#avoid-reconciliation)

Answer (score 1):

ReactJS is using Virtual DOM which is checking every time if a change occur on the DOM by comparing the stored value with the new. If a change occur then it makes the necessary changes. Thats why also we are referencing the "key" prop on lists in order for reactjs to identify them as unique and on the update of the list to check which one to render. So to sum up if you have many reducers (files) or one doesnt matter if you are correctly using the virtual dom functionality of react.

great tutorial by lin clark [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-t8eOoRsJ7M) !